# Tool to fix CodeSniffer issues in Wordpress plugin code

Tags: php, wordpress, phpcodesniffer

I have sniffed my plugin code using CodeSniffer with `WordPress` standard as mentioned at following link:-

https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards

I got a ton of issues. Now I want to fix these with help of some tool because fixing these issues manually is going to take considerable amount of time. I found such a tool here:

https://github.com/fabpot/PHP-CS-Fixer

List of CodeSniffer issues went even longer when I used this tool to fix the issues. I used following code from command prompt:

`php php-cs-fixer.phar fix /path/to/dir`

It is because of the differences in the coding standard that this Fixer is using and the `WordPress` standard that I am using to sniff my plugin code using CodeSniffer.

So how can I fix the CodeSniffer issues in my plugin using the PHP-CS-Fixer, complying with the same `WordPress` standard that is used in CodeSniffer to sniff the code?

Comment: Is anyone there to reply this?

Comment: I am still waiting.....

Comment: Normally, being sarcastic as your comments are, you will not likely find people willing to help you and spend the time.  The problem is, the tool you are looking at only does the PS1-2 standards.  As such, Wordpress has different standards.  You are either going to need to fork the tool you found and edit it for the WordPress standard as well, or bite the bullet and begin fixing your plugin manually.  A plugin should be fairly small, so you could try to correct it bit by bit.  You should try to code with a packages standards, if that is what you are building for and looking to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I was looking for someone to shed some light on this problem.

Comment: No problem.  As I said, maybe check with the author of the tool you fond to see if they are extending it, or if you could even modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the CodeSniffer. The new version implements a feature to fix violation to a coding standard automatically. But only if the particular standard already support that. For more informations please read the documentation of this feature at https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Fixing-Errors-Automatically